# Killing session after certain time and update database

Tags: php, session

I write the following php code to destroy the session after 10 sec if the user is not on the web page, but it is not functioning properly. It kills the session after 10 sec properly but it is not updating the database. To update the database I had to refresh the index.php page on the browser then it updates the database. I want that the session will be destroyed automatically  after 10 sec of start  if I close the browser or inactive,  and will update the database whether I'm on the browser or not. I don't want the refreshing thing to update the database.

```
$inactive = 10;

// check to see if $_SESSION["timeout"] is set
if (isset($_SESSION["timeout"])) {
    // calculate the session's "time to live"
    $sessionTTL = time() - $_SESSION["timeout"];
    if ($sessionTTL > $inactive) {

        $new_status= 0; 

        $checkbox = "UPDATE online SET status=($new_status) WHERE id=1 ";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($checkbox);
        // Now we execute the query passing an array toe execute();
        $results = $stmt->execute(array($new_status));
        // Extract the values from $result
                $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
        header("Location:logout.php");
       unset($_SESSION['username1']);
    }
}
```

Comment: brackets around `status=($new_status)` is for subqueries and may be contributing to its failure; remove them.

Comment: no this is ok @Fred-ii-

Comment: There is no point using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#example-1004), if you don't use them with `?` parameter markers.

Comment: this is not the solution what is I am seeking for @gre_gor

Comment: That's why I made it a comment and not an answer.

Comment: thank you :) please ans it if you have solution @gre_gor

Comment: What @Philipp answered: A script that sets the session of the user inactive will never run if the user is inactive, i.e. does not make any more requests to your server. You have to find a trigger that checks whether or not OTHER users are inactive, or you have to constantly update the date and time of the last activity in the database to allow detecting whether or not a user should be considered "inactive" during a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible the way you do it. The session is bound to a single user and if the user becomes inactive, he doesn't open any php script, which could cause an action which is bound to his session.

If you want to detect inactivity, you have to store the timestamp of the last action in the database and compare this value with the current time.

```
UPDATE user SET status=1, last_action=UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE id=?;
```

and to set the inactivity field, you could use this

```
UPDATE user SET status=0 WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - last_action > 10;
```

Comment: I am new to php can you give me reference to read about your solution ? @philipp

Comment: how will I determine the  last_action? @philipp

Comment: The first query I posted should executed for every user on each page, You have to bind the id param the the users id. The second query sets status=0 for every user which didn't anything since 10 seconds(you should increment this value to something bigger.. at least 1 minute - depends on your use case)